# As a user, is there any way to change the "confinement" of a snap package?

Tags: snap

At least go to "classic". I don't want to sidestep the issue with links or bindmounts...

Comment: It's unclear if you're asking from the perspective of a user or a developer. Please add more details.

Comment: AS a user, added to questoin

Comment: Let's assume that you are asking about changing the confinement only, not about switching channels which is quite easily done.

Comment: @karel Yes, as far as I understand the concepts

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As a user, you have a limited amount of flexibility over how you want individual snaps confined. You can install a `confinement: strict` snap in devmode, for example:

```
$ sudo snap install --devmode <snap name>
```

You can also install a `confinement: devmode` snap in "jail" mode (i.e. treat it as strictly confined):

```
$ sudo snap install --jailmode <snap name>
```

What you cannot do, however, is install a `confinement: classic` as anything other than classic, or similarly a `confinement: <not classic>` snap as classic.

This limitation isn't to be annoying, it's because `confinement: classic` snaps are built entirely differently than `confinement: <not classic>` snaps, and in virtually all cases running them under another model would result in a segfault or something similar. This has to do with the fact that `confinement: classic` snaps do not use the `core` snap as its rootfs/execution environment like the other types of confinement, so it finds things like libc in a totally different place.

In general, I don't recommend taking advantage of the ability to install snaps under different confinement models unless you're utilizing them as a developer testing out your snap. Otherwise you'll be using the snap in a way that is probably completely untested by the snap author, and may or may not work properly.